# mix-blend-mode with backdrop-filter: blur triggers glitches on Chrome

Tags: css, blur, mix-blend-mode

On Windows, with Chrome, I try to use `backdrop-filter: blur` and `mix-blend-mode: soft-light`, but every time my cursor moves on the Chrome Tabs, rectangle glitches occur at the top of the page.

I don't know how to fix it...

[image]

```css
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .background {
    background-color: #0000ff;
  }

  .blur-leftside {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
    backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
    mix-blend-mode: soft-light;
    background: #ffffff;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="background">
      <div class="blur-leftside"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```